# Java poker hand evaluator to not working

Tags: java, arrays, poker

I'm trying to figure out how to pass this but actually be working. I am afraid I'm getting false positives.

```
public static boolean hasPair(Card[] cards) {
     Card[] pair= new Card[5];
     for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
     {
       for(int j=i+1; j<5; j++)
       {
         if(pair[i].equals(cards[j]))
           return true;
       }
      }
    return false;
```

i updated to this. Is it right or am i wrong again? This is driving me nuts but im still trying i just will not sleep for the next two days.

I'm not allowed to use collections either so that kinda stinks.
heres my `Junit`

```
public void testhasPair(){

         Card[] pair= new Card[5];

                pair[0]=new Card(5,1);
                pair[1] = new Card(1,1);
                pair [2]=new Card(1,2);
                pair [3]=new Card(3,3);
                pair [4]=new Card(6,3);
            assertTrue(PokerHandEvaluator.hasPair(pair));
```

Comment: Go back to the questions you have asked in the past and click the green check mark next to the correct answer.  This allows you to reward people for their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use, or just read and learn from, one of the many poker libraries out there. There's a good list here: http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/poker-hand-evaluator-roundup

Answer (score 1):

```
Card[] pair= new Card[5];
```

you haven't innitialized the elements of the pair array, so in effect you are comparing the parameter cards to null. Plua you are using == to compare cards, which checks to see if the cards are the exact same card, which isn't right.

Comment: i got 5 others but i been working on the poker game for a week and still cranking at it

Comment: @JavaProgrammer Make sure to implement equals correctly on `Card`